# How to read or get what text is in textview

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a textView whose text is randomly generated by this Java code in Android Studio each time a button is pressed:

```
Button green_changer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button);

        green_changer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Resources res = getResources();

                myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.colorArray);

                String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];

                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
                tv.setText(q);
            }
        });
```

How can I use Java to figure out, get, or retrieve which string is being displayed at any moment?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Define these variables outside of the onCreate() function (ie. make them global variables)
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
String textViewString;    

Button green_changer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button);


    green_changer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Resources res = getResources();

            myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.colorArray);

            String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];

            tv.setText(q);
        }
    });
```

Now whenever you want to know what the string is inside the TextView is do the following call.

```
textViewString = tv.getText();
```

And now the textViewString holds the string that is in your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = ...;
final String text = tv.getText().toString()
```